# ant run.client parameter passing dunno directory to place i/p file

Tags: ant, apache-axis

i am trying to run a sample code from axis2-1.6.2-bin samples , the name of the sample is soapwithattachments . . i have run the generate.service command to deploy the aar file . . but when i run the ant run.client ank.txt c:// . . it says that ank.txt does not exist in the project "SOAPWithAttachmentsSample" the build.xml file does not give me any idea of where to place the file ank.txt . . . please help , i need this for my project and the deadline is approaching fast

```
<project name="SOAPWithAttachmentsSample" default="generate.service">  
    <property environment="env" />  
    <property name="axis2.home" value="../../" />  
    <property name="axis2.repo" value="${axis2.home}/repository" />  
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />  
    <property name="client.classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />  
    <path id="axis.classpath">  
        <fileset dir="${axis2.home}/lib">  
            <include name="*.jar" />  
        </fileset>  
        <pathelement location="build/swaSampleClient.jar" />  
    </path>  

    <target name="generate.service" depends="compile">  
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/sample-swa.aar">    
            <fileset dir="resources/">  
                <include name="META-INF/services.xml" />  
            </fileset>  
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/classes">  
                <include name="sample/soapwithattachments/service/**/*.class" />  
            </fileset>  
        </jar>  
        <copy file="${build.dir}/sample-swa.aar" tofile="${axis2.home}/repository/services/sample-swa.aar" overwrite="true" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="compile">  
        <mkdir dir="${client.classes.dir}" />  
        <!-- Compile client -->  
        <javac debug="on"  srcdir="src" destdir="${client.classes.dir}">  
            <classpath refid="axis.classpath" />  
        </javac>  
    </target>  
    <target name="check-parameters">  
        <condition property="parameters.set">  
            <and>  
                <isset property="dest" />  
                <isset property="file" />  
            </and>  
        </condition>  
        <!-- This is a hack to get a if-else working in ant. Some much more "ANTy" person is welcome to improve this -->  
        <antcall target="print-usage" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="print-usage" unless="parameters.set">  
        <echo message="ant -Dfile <file to be transfered>  -Ddest <name of the destination file>" />  
    </target>  

    <target name="run.client" depends="compile,check-parameters" if="parameters.set">  
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/swaSampleClient.jar">  
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/classes">  
                <include name="sample/soapwithattachments/client/**/*.class" />  
            </fileset>  
        </jar>  
        <java classname="sample.soapwithattachments.client.SWAClient" classpathref="axis.classpath" fork="true">  
            <arg value="-file" />  
            <arg value="${file}" />  
            <arg value="-dest" />  
            <arg value="${dest}" />  
            <jvmarg value="-Daxis2.repo=${axis2.repo}" />  
        </java>  
    </target>  
    <target name="clean">  
        <delete dir="build" />  
    </target>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the command line `ant run.client ank.txt c://`, and is interpreting all the arguments as targets to execute.  The target `run.client` exists, but the other two obviously don't, hence your error message.  From looking at the run.client target, it looks like you need to set the build properties for `file` and `dest`.  Take a look at the usage target in your build.xml.  It shows the syntax for passing things in as build properties to ant, which is to use `-D<property>=<value>`.  In your case, you probably want the following:

`ant run.client -Dfile=ank.txt -Ddest=c://`

Comment: Thanks a lot David !! i got the command running . . .